# GCP Cloud Monitoring Alert Not Triggering as Expected for Endpoint Success Rate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm currently facing an issue while setting up a GCP Cloud Monitoring alert to monitor the success rate of a specific endpoint using the provided MQL (Monitoring Query Language). I have two problems:

- **Retest Window:** When I set a retest window of 30 minutes, I noticed that the alert policy graph shows some points that consistently stay below the threshold for more than an hour, and yet the alert hasn't triggered.
- **Threshold and Row Count Filtering:** I attempted to make the alert consider only the aligned data points that had more than 20 requests in an hour. However, when applying this additional filter, the alert doesn't trigger as expected. I'm unsure why this filter is affecting the alert's behavior.

First, I tried to create the alert using the following query:

```
fetch resource::logging_based_metric
| filter endpoint_name = @endpoint()
| {
    filter Codigo_http = "200"
  ;
    ident
  }
| align delta (1h)
| group_by [endpoint_name]
| ratio 
| condition val() < 0.99
```

This alert did not triggered when the point stayed below the threshold for more than 30 minutes.
On the second point, I did some modification to the first query to acchieve it:

```
fetch resource::logging_based_metric
| filter endpoint_name == @endpoint()
| {
    filter Codigo_http == '200'
    | align rate(1h)
    | group_by [endpoint_name], [row_count: row_count()]
    ;
    ident
    | align rate(1h)
    | group_by [endpoint_name], [row_count: row_count()]
    | filter val() > 20
  }
| ratio
| condition val() < 0.9
```

However, this query doesn't work since I tried to force a condition that is always true and the alert didn't trigger.